# Reference a variable using a string

Tags: vb.net, variables, basic, refer

I have a few variables called: _2sVal, _3sVal, _4sVal, etc
I want to change each of their values through a loop. 
Like:

```
For i = 1 To 10
    'set the value
Next
```

I've tried putting them in a dictionary like:

```
Dim varDict As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
varDict.Add("2sVal", _2sVal)
varDict.Add("3sVal", _3sVal)
varDict.Add("4sVal", _4sVal)
```

I can retrieve the value using

```
MsgBox(varDict(i.ToString & "sVal"))
```

But when I try to change it like

```
varDict(i.ToString & "sVal") = 5
```

It doesn't do anything. No errors or exceptions either, just the value stays unchanged

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: "doesn't seem to be working" is not a clear problem description. In what _way_ does it seem to not be working? How did you determine it was not working, and how did you _expect_ it to work?

Comment: Well I can retrieve the value using MsgBox(varDict(i.ToString & "sVal"))
But when I try to change it like varDict(i.ToString & "sVal") = 5
It doesn't do anything. No errors or exceptions either, just the value stays unchanged.

Comment: Please click the "edit" button and update your question with this information. That sort of information belongs in the question, not in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using

```
varDict.Add("4sVal", _4sVal)
```

You are not putting the `_4sVal` variable inside the dictionary, but its value.

Then, changing the dictionary will not change the `_4sVal`, since there is no reference of it inside the dictionary.

What I mean is

```
varDict("4sVal") = 5
```

will change the value of dictionary but not the variable `_4sVal` itself.

I think the correct to do is define that variables as Properties, defined like:

```
Property _4sVal As Integer
    Get
        Return varDict("4sVal")
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        varDict("4sVal") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

This way you will not have to change anything in the rest of your code. It will be transparent.